# Store redux data that can be accessible with swift and java

Tags: javascript, java, swift, react-native, redux

I want to rewrite my React Native application with Java for Android and Swift for iOS. The thing is, I don't want to lose application data so that the user has to set up the application again.

Imagine we're on version 2.0.0 (Written in RN) and version 3.0.0 is written in Java and Swift. I want to store my redux store somewhere so that I can retrieve that on the native side and after the user updates the app.

I found [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-plist) to store app data into a `.plist` file that can be accessed with Swift later on. I don't know if that's the right way for iOS and also I have no clue of what should I do for Android side.

Note that I can't get the config file from the network and I'm using `redux-persist` to persist the data for my app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't mention how you're storing the data right now, but you should look at the source code for whatever you're storing it with right now -- there's probably native code in the library you're using for persistence that you can use in your future Java/Swift version.

Comment: Actually, I'm using redux-persist. I assumed it's stored inside the AsyncStorage but I found that it's using a different method.

Comment: Check the documentation for v6 -- you can pass in a storage engine type.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I don't want to change my storage engine, this way the current version (RN) would be affected and we don't want to change such a thing. Any suggestions for storing data somewhere on the device so that we're able to read it later?

Comment: Which engine are you currently using with redux persist?

Comment: It's currently `redux-persist/lib/storage`. I read the documentation and it says it defaults to `localStorage` for the web but I'm not sure what's is used for RN. Is it possible that it's AsyncStorage?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can integrate a minimum react native module within your new native apps, and make it provide a data migration path for your existing customers. Not sure how you will solve this with a decent UX though.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps